# Euler angles and inertia tensor

Tags: rotational-kinematics, rotation, moment-of-inertia

Please note:  What I'm looking for is $\alpha_0$ and $\beta_0$ in a form similar to Eq.(3) that will eventually give Eq.(1).  Note that the inertia tensor is not a rotation matrix so I'm not trying to convert a rotation matrix into Euler form since $\mathbb{I}$ is not a rotation matrix to start with.  *As a result the proposed duplicates are not really relevant to what I'm trying to do.*

It is well-known that the inertia tensor can be brought to diagonal form by a rotation:
$$
\mathbb{I}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
I_{xx}&I_{xy}&I_{xz}\\
I_{xy}&I_{yy}&I_{yz}\\
I_{xz}&I_{yz}&I_{zz}\end{array}\right) \to \mathbb{I}'=R(\Omega) \mathbb{I}R^{-1}(\Omega)
=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} I_1&0&0\\ 0&I_2&0\\ 0&0&I_3\end{array}\right)\, , 
\qquad R(\Omega)\in SO(3)\, .
$$
The rotation $R(\Omega)$ can be factorized in terms of Euler angles - say
$$
R(\Omega)=R_z(\gamma)R_y(\beta) R_z(\alpha)\, .
$$
Is there a systematic way of finding the Euler angles $(\gamma,\beta,\alpha)$ that will diagonalize the inertia tensor in terms of the entries of the $\mathbb{I}$ tensor?

Since
$$
R_z(\alpha)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \cos (\alpha ) & \sin (\alpha ) & 0 \\
 -\sin (\alpha ) & \cos (\alpha ) & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\qquad 
R_y(\beta)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \cos (\beta ) & 0 & \sin (\beta ) \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -\sin (\beta ) & 0 & \cos (\beta ) \\
\end{array}
\right)\, .
$$
one strategy is to find $\beta,\alpha$ so that
$$
R_y(\beta)R_z(\alpha) \mathbb{I} R_z(-\alpha)R_y(-\beta)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
A&B&0\\
B&C&0\\
0&0&E
\end{array}\right)\, . \tag{1}
$$
A final rotation by $R_z(\gamma)$ would diagonalize the remaining $2\times 2$ subspace.

I started with the idea of finding *consecutive* transformations that would do the trick, *i.e.* started by finding
$\alpha_0$ so that
$$
R_z(\alpha_0) \mathbb{I} R_z(-\alpha_0)
=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&c\\
b&d&0\\
c&0&e
\end{array}\right)\, . \tag{2}
$$
Finding $\alpha_0$ follows from matrix multiplication by setting
$$
\cos(\alpha_0)=\frac{\mathbb{I}_{xz}}{\sqrt{\mathbb{I}_{xz}^2+\mathbb{I}_{yz}^2}}\, ,\quad 
 \sin(\alpha_0)=\frac{\mathbb{I}_{yz}}{\sqrt{\mathbb{I}_{xz}^2+\mathbb{I}_{yz}^2}}\, , \tag{3}
$$
so $\alpha_0$ is given explicitly in terms of entries of $\mathbb{I}$.  The entries $a, b, c, d,e$ that result from this matrix multiplication now depend on $\alpha_0$ and other entries of $\mathbb{I}$, but the inertia tensor now has the form of Eq.(2) so I use this as the starting point for the next step.

I then tried to find $R_y(\beta_0)$ to make $c=0$ but this simply moves the $0$ to another location:
$$
R_y(\beta_0)R_z(\alpha_0) \mathbb{I} R_z(-\alpha_0)R_y(\beta_0)
= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a'&b'&0\\
b'&d'&c'\\
0&c'&e
\end{array}\right)\, .
$$
One can try variations on the $R_zR_yR_z$ form, say $R_xR_yR_x$ but it appears the same basic result remains.

Thus it seems the only way to proceed is to start with $R_y(\beta)R_z(\alpha) \mathbb{I} R_z(-\alpha)R_y(\beta)$ and *simulteaneously* find $\alpha,\beta$ that will bring $\mathbb{I}$ to the block diagonal form of (1), and this leads to highly non-trivial equations to solve, with possibly no analytical solution in terms of $I_{ab}$.

If it is not possible to solve the general case, is it possible to solve some specific specialized cases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that any rotation can be represented by 3 Euler angles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186359/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140670/discussion-on-question-by-zerothehero-euler-angles-and-inertia-tensor).